# The remainder left out when $8^{2n}-62^{2n+1}$ is divided by $9$ is?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, divisibility, binomial-theorem

I was solving this question while practicing binomial theorem, and my $1^{st}$ thought was to substitute $n=0$ for which I get $-61$ and find the remainder which I get as $7$. And when I checked the answer it was $2$. So I tried substituting $0$ again to check my answer, and I got $7$ again, as the remainder. I substituted $n=1$ and still got $7$ as the remainder. I am really confused by the book's solution too. Can someone please say where I made the mistake?
**Book answer:**
$$8^{2n}-62^{2n+1}= \ (9-1)^{2n}- \ (63-1)^{2n+1}$$
$$= (\ ^{2n}C_{0}9^{2n}-^{2n}C_{1}9^{2n-1}+ \ ... \ +^{2n}C_{2n}9^{0}) \ - \ (^{2n+1}C_{0}63^{2n}+ \ ... \ ^{2n+1}C_{2n+1}63^0)$$
$$=9(k_1+7k_2)+2$$
$$=9\beta + 2 \ \ \ (\text{where $k_1$,$k_2$ and $\beta$ are some integers.})$$

Comment: -61 divided by 9 means quotient (-7) so remainder as (-61-(-63)) = 2. The book solution relies on last term of the bionomial expansion to prove that. All other terms are divisible by 9.

Comment: Oh! I really did not know that was the way to calculate remainders for negative numbers. I just divided normally. Thanks I got it now

Comment: you would have got $-7$ which is same as 2.

Comment: The book solution's too hard. $8\equiv-1\bmod9$ and $62\equiv-1\bmod9$ so $8^{2n}-62^{2n+1}\equiv(-1)^{2n}-(-1)^{2n+1}=1--1=2\bmod9$.

Comment: Thank you @GerryMyerson your solution is simple and I got it :)

Answer (score 1):

For $n=0$ we have $$1-62^{1}=-61=9\cdot(-7)+2$$ where $\beta=-7$, so the remainder is $2.$

---

The [Division Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Division_Theorem) tell us that for every pair of integers $a,b$ where $b\neq 0$, there exist unique integers $q,r$ such that $$a=qb+r$$
and $0\leq r< |b|$. Comparing above we have $a=-61$ and $b=9$ which give $q=-7$ and $r=2$ with $0\leq r<9$.

---

From the book's solution $$ (\ ^{2n}C_{0}9^{2n}-^{2n}C_{1}9^{2n-1}+ \ ... \ +\color{red}{^{2n}C_{2n}9^{0}}) \ - \ (^{2n+1}C_{0}63^{2n}+ \ ... \ -\color{\red}{^{2n+1}C_{2n+1}63^0})$$

All the non-red terms above are divisible by $9$, moreover since $63=9\times 7$, we can pull a factor of $7$ from the second bracket after excluding the red term. Since the two red terms are $1$ we can re-write it as $$ (\ ^{2n}C_{0}9^{2n}-^{2n}C_{1}9^{2n-1}+ \ ... \ ) \ - \ (^{2n+1}C_{0}63^{2n}+ \ ... \ )+\color{red}{^{2n}C_{2n}9^{0}}+\color{\red}{^{2n+1}C_{2n+1}63^0}$$
$$=(\ ^{2n}C_{0}9^{2n}-^{2n}C_{1}9^{2n-1}+ \ ... \ ) \ - \ \color{blue}{7}(^{2n+1}C_{0}9^{2n}7^{2n-1}+ \ ... \ )+2$$
$$=9(k_{1}+7k_{2})+2$$
$$=9\beta+2$$

where $k_1$,$k_2$ and $\beta$ are some integers as required.

Answer (score 0):

Your technique and answer are correct, but it can be made easier. Building on @MathLover's comment, work modulo $9$ so $a\equiv b\implies a^n\equiv b^n$, because $a-b|a^n-b^n$. So$$8\equiv62\equiv-1\implies8^{2n}-62^{2n+1}\equiv(-1)^{2n}-(-1)^{2n+1}=2(-1)^{2n}=2.$$

Comment: I am not really familiar with modular math, but this is a good reason to learn it!

Comment: @BrainNuke Try Sec. 2 [here](http://math.mit.edu/~goemans/18310S15/modarithm-algebra-notes.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, let $f(n)=8^{2n}-62^{2n+1}$. Then $f(n+1)-f(n)=63 (8^{2n} - 61 \cdot 62^{2 n + 1})$ is a multiple of $9$. Therefore, the remainder of $f(n)$ when divided by $9$ is the same for all $n$. Since $f(0)=-61$, the remainder is always $2$.